# TortoiseSVN - Recover content of shelved files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, unshelve

I have some files that I cannot unshelve for some reason. ("<Path to some .java file> is not a working copy", but that's not exactly the topic.)

Is there any way to recover the contents without going through the "Unshelve" dialog? Double-clicking and right-clicking on the files in the dialog does nothing.

There exist files in the .svn directory with the expected names, but there tend to me multiple related files and I can't glean the meaning of the various files. For example:
[image]
Does the file suffixed with `.work` have the contents as they were when I shelved it? Then what is `.base`? They are different, but I can't generally tell which file's the one I want. And I want the file as it was when I shelved it.

Also: Does SVN have a problem with spaces in paths?
[image]
For some reason there's a CR, LF and then a space between "Eclipse" and "Workspace", where there should only be a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I switched to a different branch and now unshelving worked. (It might be possible that I switched branches between shelving and unshelving, but honestly that ought to just work.)
Thanks, TortoiseSVN, for the very expressive error message that was very helpful in finding that solution.